# highcharts - how to change width of columns but only for PDF, exporting?

Tags: javascript, css, highcharts

I have a problem with overwriting column widths only for PDF, i.e. for export.
I don't understand why it doesn't work..

maybe I can't override this pointWidth value?

can't find it in the documentation

on the website I have pointWidth : 45 but also on PDF. I need 15 in pdf.

I was trying :

```
 .
 .
 .
   
      chart: {
           ....
      },
      plotOptions: {
        series: {
          dataLabels: {
            useHTML: true,
          },
          pointWidth: 45,
        },
        column: {
          stacking: "normal",
          dataLabels: {
            enabled: true,
            verticalAlign: "bottom",
          },
        },
      },
      exporting: {
          chartOptions: {
                column: {
                pointWidth: 15,
              }
          }
      },
    });
 .
 .
 .
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change pointWidth for all column series, you need you refer to `plotOptions.column` (or `plotOptions.series` - for all series types).

```
  exporting: {
      chartOptions: {
        plotOptions: {
          column: {
            pointWidth: 10,
          }
        }
      }
    },
```

In the case of particular series, it would be looks like the following:

```
  exporting: {
    chartOptions: {
      series: [{
        pointWidth: 10,
      }, {
        pointWidth: 50,
      }]
    }
  },
```

**Demo:**
https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/yw6qrz43/